# ios-deploy not found under OS X El Capitan

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

ios-deploy not found error when running from command line "ionic run ios --device" under El Capitan. Have re-installed ionic and node, still no luck.

Answer (score 47):

After a few tries of re-installing my environment and even compiling xcode, the following did the trick.

From your command line enter the following:

```
sudo npm install -g ios-deploy --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

Comment: Thank you. I was running appium-doctor and this helps!

Answer (score 12):

I was also having this problem building on Catalina. Turns out all I had to do was disconnect my iPhone from the USB port.

1. Disconnect any iOS devices from USB
2. Run the command and wait until it finishes
3. Reconnect the device

Answer (score 3):

With Catalina 10.15.1 I got it working by installing ios-deploy with brew.

```
npm uninstall -g ios-deploy   
brew install ios-deploy
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this also:

```
sudo npm install --global --unsafe-perm ios-deploy
```